# Bash: concatenate two variables with colon in the middle results in unpredictable behaviour

Tags: bash, carriage-return

I have a directory containing files that start with a date.

```
for file in ./my_dir/*; do
    first_line=$(head -n 1 "$file")
    echo $file:$first_line
done
```

This prints as below, which is expected:

> ./my_dir/file.md:23/07/2023

When I switch the order of the `$file` and `$first_line` like this:

```
for file in ./my_dir/*; do
    first_line=$(head -n 1 "$file")
    echo $first_line:$file
done
```

The output becomes:

> :./my_dir/file.md

The `$first_line` is completely ignored. My expectation was it to be like this:

> 23/07/2023:./my_dir/file.md

I've tried changing the delimiter and the first line of the files. Using `${first_line}:${file}`, `"${first_line}:${file}"` didn't work too.

Comment: You should use : `echo "${first_line}:${file}"`

Comment: Your file has carriage returns in it. Remove them with `dos2unix`

Comment: @Paolo, already tried. Forgot to mention what I've already tried.

Comment: @Barmar, that was the case. Thank you!

Comment: What operating system is this? I found that `for file in ./my_dir` will just return ./my_dir and not files in that directory.

Comment: @HaiVu, Ubuntu, WSL. Yes, I missed that part while creating a minimal reproducible example. It's fixed now.

Comment: Quick workaround: Replace `head -n 1 "$file"` with `head -n 1 "$file" | dos2unix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your solution on both macOS and Ubuntu 22.04 and got:

```
head: error reading './my_dir': Is a directory
```

That is because `for file in ./my_dir` only return `./my_dir`. It does not return a list of files in that directory.

I found the following works. Notice the wildcard:

```bash
for file in ./my_dir/*
do
        first_line=$(head -n 1 "$file")
        echo "$first_line:$file"
done
```

## Update

If you don't mind using awk, the following also works:

```bash
awk 'FNR==1 {print $0 ":" FILENAME}' ./my_dir/*
```

The `FNR == 1` expression says *if the line is the first line in a file*.

## Update 2

Here is an awk command which strips the trailing CRLF, which should fix your problem:

```bash
awk 'FNR==1 {sub(/[\r\n]*$/, ""); print $0 ":" FILENAME}' ./my_dir/*
```

## Update 3

Here is how to do it in bash: Use the `tr` command to strip the CRLF:

```bash
for file in ./my_dir/*
do
        first_line=$(head -n 1 "$file"| tr -d "\r\n")
        echo "$first_line:$file"
done
```

Comment: Please see my most recent comment under the question. I do like your solution with `awk` but since the "error" was caused by a carriage return character I think removing it is a more general solution.

Comment: Oh my bad, the solution with `awk` doesn't work because the first line still contains return carriage.

Comment: `awk -v RS='\r\n'`  also works.